# If a new object is instantiating here (if obj == "")

Tags: java

I'm wondering if a new object is creating here:

```
String obj;
if(obj == "") {
}
```

and here:

```
if(obj.equals("")){}
```

I mean is the object like new String("") instantiating for those both cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Kind of**.

You're right that the program will actually reference a full `String` object, containing the value `""`.  However, this isn't strictly created at the point the method is invoked.  The Strings for (compile-time constant) string literals are created in a JVM-wide constant pool when the class is loaded into the VM, and identical constants share the same strings.

Since there's almost certainly a class in the JVM itself that references the empty string literal, the string pool will already contain the object corresponding to `""` and so your class won't actually cause a new object to be created.

Comment: Hm, I thought the OP was asking about `obj`, not `""`; if it was `""` then this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, `obj` is just a reference to nowhere in those cases. You'll get an error saying that `obj` hasn't been initialized in either case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If string pool already contains the string "", then no new object will be constructed. Otherwise of course a new String object is constructed and put to the string pool.

Comment: Actually, it's put into the string pool at class loading, not when first encountered.  So either way a new object won't be created at that point.

Answer (score 1):

No. There will be no object created for `obj`. Prehaps you're mixing up with C++ where the default constructor would have been called?

In

```
String obj;
if(obj == "") {
}
```

the check `obj == ""` will fail (since `obj` will equal `null` and `""` will not).

In

```
if(obj.equals("")){}
```

you'll get a `NullPointerException`, since `obj` is `null`, which cannot be dispatched on.

---

If the question is whether or not an empty string is created for the purpose of comparing, the answer is: Not at runtime, but at compile time. Compare it with the question, "Is `i == 5` creating an integer of value `5` here?" Well, not really.

Answer (score 1):

That code does not even build. And the compiler tells you why:

```
"The local variable obj may not have been initialized"
```